# Error posting Flurry event on android

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

When I try to use:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent("Read_article", articleParams);
```

it returns `FlurryEventRecordStatus.kFlurryEventFailed`

I am not able to find what is causing this issue and I haven't found any mention of the same in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct method from https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/events/android/#capture-event-parameters

```
// Capture author info & user status
Map<String, String> articleParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

//param keys and values have to be of String type
articleParams.put("Author", "John Q");
articleParams.put("User_Status", "Registered");

//up to 10 params can be logged with each event
FlurryAgent.logEvent("Article_Read", articleParams);
```

I suspect that the event is triggered with parameters not set.

Another likely possibility is the event is triggered immediately after the call to FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY); in some cases such events fail to record. If you suspect this is the case trigger the event after a brief pause.

Comment: We found that events logged immediately after init() (e.g: An App launch event) fail. Yahoo should definitely consider this race condition a bug. If you agree, please vote for it here: https://github.com/flurry/android-AnalyticsSample/issues/1